# <Twilio/Python> jsonify call logs

Tags: python, api, twilio, twilio-api

I am following the Twilio tutorial to setup an iOS project. Since it requires a backend, I have opted for Python (I am an iOS developer with 'zero' knowledge about Python) So the question might probably be a dumb one, but I do not get the proper syntax to look for.

**Objective:**
To fetch all the call logs and conference logs & return them as JSON response.

**My Code:**

```
@app.route('/getRecordings', methods=['GET'])
def getRecordings():
    client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_AUTH_TOKEN)
    recordings = []
    for record in client.calls.list():
        recordings.append(record.sid)
    conferences = []
    for conf in client.conferences.list():
        conferences.append(conf.sid)
    return jsonify(calls=recordings, conferences=conferences)
```

**Response:**
I am getting the proper response, since I have appended only the SID property of each call.

```
{
  "calls": [
    "CAxxx",
    "CAxxx",
  ],
  "conferences": [
    "CFxxx",
    "CFxxx",
  ]
}
```

But I would like to get the complete details of each record as shown in the output tab of this sample from Twilio (Reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/conference)
When I try to JSONify the record, it says it cannot JSONify the object of this type.

I understand that I should convert the object to a model and append it, but how can I do that? Any links or leads to help getting this sorted are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want the full JSON response proxied to your application, then you may find it easier to avoid the Twilio library and just make requests to the JSON API endpoints and send the response straight on.

For example, to get the [list of calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call#calls-list-resource) with Python's [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/) you would do something like this:

```
@app.route('/getCalls', methods=['GET'])
def getCalls():
  url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID/Calls/.json'
  request = requests.get(url, auth=(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN)

  resp = Response(response=request.text,
                  status=200,
                  mimetype="application/json")
  return resp
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list of dictionaries with the required values. Something like this:

```
for record in client.calls.list():
    call = {"account_sid": record.account_sid, "api_version": record.api_version, "date_created": record.date_created, "etc": record.etc}
    recordings.append(call)
```

That should give you a response as follows:

```
{
  "calls": [
    {
      "accound_sid": "1234", 
      "api_version": "2010-04-01", 
      "date_created": "Wed, 18 Aug 2010 20:20:06 +0000", 
      "etc": "etc", 
    },
    {
      "accound_sid": "4321", 
      "api_version": "2010-04-01", 
      "date_created": "Wed, 18 Aug 2010 20:20:06 +0000", 
      "etc": "etc", 
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I was wondering if there would be anyway in `Twilio/Python` that would directly give the JSON response. Something like, create a `Model` object and pass the response to it, and it will handle the `JSONifying`. Anyways, I think I should opt for this at least for now. (y)